# Git remove file from a range of commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I need to remove a folder from my repo in certain commits. It was added in commit `a` and removed in commit `b` and was added again in commit `c` as submodule.
Now I want to remove it from the commits between (including) `a` and `b`.

I have it as far as I have to do something like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --remove lib --ignore-submodules' 7a08959f87681decc15ad5a272bbada66c3272e8 goodbye_cmake
```

But I don't know how I can add the end (`b`). It deletes it from all the commits from `a` to the last commit of goodbye_cmake (i.e. HEAD)... So what do I have to change that I still have my submodule in the last few (~30) commits?

Thanks for all your time!
- Fodinabor

Answer (score 1):

[BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is a nice alternative to filter-branch, and it's [blessed by github](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/#using-the-bfg). It only changes your history and won't remove any files currently in the project, so it should remove the old directory up to commit `b` like you want. The invocation will end up looking like:

```
java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders directory_name your_repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question, you already have the answer (almost):

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --remove tests/files/ceac_analysis_data_* --ignore-submodules'  10e8e892b49a4657a3b36ef4ca0a524b8a26a438..HEAD
```

So the syntax is

```
$ git filter-branch *options* a..b
```

Instead of

```
$ git filter-branch *options* a b`
```

Comment: `git filter-repo` https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/ is now recommended when you try to run `git filter-branch`